# Extraer índice de las columnas con valor máximo (más de un máximo) para cada row en R

Tags: r

[image: Data frame con valores]

Quisiera obtener los índices de las columnas con el valor máximo para cada row. 
Mediante max.col sistemáticamente en vez de obtener los índices de las columnas con el valor máximo, obtengo simplemente los índices de las columnas con valores.

[image: Aplicando max.col]

Gracias de antemano

Comment: por favor añade texto y no imágenes

Answer (score 1):

Usando R base puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
apply(durx, MARGIN=1, FUN=function(fila) {which.max(fila)[1]})
```

**Detalle**:

- Con `function(fila) {which.max(fila)[1]}` si `fila` representa efectivamente un vector para una fila de una matriz o dataframe, obtenemos el índice del elemento máximo, usamos `[1]` para obtener solo un valor, el primero que cumpla la condición, si nos interesa tener todos los máximos, deberíamos dejar el resultado como lista y no aplicar `unlist()`.
- Con `apply(durx, MARGIN=1, FUN=..)` aplicamos el código anterior a cada fila ( `MARGIN=1`) de la matriz/data.frame `durx`.

Si sabemos que solo hay un único valor máximo por fila, podemos optar por una sintaxis mucho más acotada:

```
apply(durx, 1, which.max)
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, la situación descrita no se ajusta a la peculiaridad de los datos, existen filas enteras con NA, y filas con más de un máximo. Es por ello que la respuesta que buscava va más en la línia de la dada por @mpaladino

Answer (score 0):

## Respuesta corta

Con esta función:

```
funcion_jeder <- function (matriz) {
  lista <- apply(matriz, 1, function (x) {
    if (all(sapply(x, is.na))) {NA        #Si todos los valores de la fila son NA
    } else {
      which(x == max(x, na.rm = TRUE))
    } #Si algún valor no es NA las posiciones de todos los máximos.
  }
  )   # Cierra apply
  lista_igualada <- lapply(lista, `length<-`, max(lengths(lista)))
  salida <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, lista_igualada) 
  colnames(salida) <- paste0("Columna", 1:ncol(salida))
  salida
}
```

## Datos de prueba

Creamos un datos de prueba con una estructura similar a los tuyos. Tienen dos complicaciones adicionales que podrían presentarse en datos empíricos:

1. Empates. Hay varias columnas con el valor máximo.
2. `NA`. Hay filas que tienen solo `NA`, por lo tanto no reportan valor máximo.

   set.seed(2018)
   vector <- floor((runif(90, 1, 10)))
   vector <-  vector[sample(c(TRUE, NA), length(vector), prob = c(0.5, 0.5), replace = TRUE)]
   durx <- matrix(vector, nrow = 9)
   durx <- rbind(durx, rep(NA, 10)) #Agrego una fila de solo NA

## Con `apply`, `which.max` y `unlist`

```
 test1 <- apply(durx, 1, which.max)
 class(test1)
```

Regresa una lista que se puede simplificar con `unlist`.

```
unlist(test1)
length(unlist(test1))
[1] 9
```

> El largo del vector no coincide cuando hay filas que solo tienen valores `NA`. Podría ser problemática si posteriormente vas a usar este vector para hacer un subset.

## Con `apply` y subset de lista.

```
test2 <- apply(durx, 1, function(x) {which.max(x)[1]})
test2 
[1]  7  2  7  7  5  1  6  4  4 NA
length(test2)
[1] 10
```

Esta es la mejor opción, ya que maneja el caso especial de la fila 10. Si nos interesa obtener solamente el primer índice de columna que contiene el valor máximo de cada fila.

> El desempate es silencioso, `which.max` lo aplica por defecto y no hay posibilidad de cambiarlo con un argumento a la función.

## Una lista con todos los índices que tienen valor máximo.

Para obtener todos los índices de las columnas con valor máximo por fila no hay alternativa a crear una función que produzca una lista, de ese modo podemos trabajar con vectores de largo desigual.

```
test3 <- apply(durx, 1, function (x) {
  if (all(sapply(x, is.na))) {NA        #Si todos los valores de la fila son NA
    } else {
      which(x == max(x, na.rm = TRUE))} #Si algún valor no es NA las posiciones de todos los máximos.
                                      }
               )
```

El código es enredado, porque maneja el caso en el que todos los elementos de la fila son NA. De lo contrario `max` produce un `-Inf`, que en el test de `x ==` produce un `integer(0)`. Mejor que saque un `NA` explícito.

Esta función anónima produce una lista con largos desiguales, que luego podemos pasar a data.frame, previa igualación de los vectores internos de la lista con NA.

```
lista_igualada <- lapply(test3, `length<-`, max(lengths(lista_igualada)))
do.call(rbind.data.frame, lista_igualada)
```

Después le podrías poner unos nombres mejores a las columnas resultantes, dependiendo del uso que le vayas a dar.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, me has solucionado un grave problema !

Comment: Quizás es enredar demasiado las cosas, pero mi idea inicial era conseguir que los máximos o NA de cada fila se mantuvieran en la misma fila, así pues la pregunta es si podria crearse una nueva columna para cada máximo extra en cada fila tal que si mi fila 484 tiene 3 máximos, que los tres máximos aparezcan en las posiciones [484,1] , [484,2] , [484,3] del output generado. Tenga o no la respuesta reitero mi agradecimiento.

Comment: Ahi va la solución a mi propio comentario. Se crea un dataframe vacio y se rellena mediante un for loop usando el código de @mpaladino con algunos retoques.  output3<-data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = nrow(durx), ncol = 3))
 for (i in 1:nrow(durx)){
   if (output3[i,1]<- all(sapply(i, is.na))) {NA        
    } else {
      output3[i,1]<-which(durx[i,] == max(durx[i,], na.rm = TRUE))[1]
      output3[i,2]<-which(durx[i,] == max(durx[i,], na.rm = TRUE))[2]
      output3[i,3]<-which(durx[i,] == max(durx[i,], na.rm = TRUE))[3]
      } 
               
}

Comment: Actualicé la respuesta con una solución más general para tu problema. Además no requiere usar bucles, se resuelve todo con manipulación de listas. De hecho al principio puse una función que hace lo que estás buscando. OJO: si vas a usarla en producción (código que se ejecuta sin supervisión) deberías testearla con cuidado. Ya probé y funciona bien también en escenarios sin empates, pero tiene muchas coerciones de estructuras y habría que ver cómo se aplican las reglas de coerción en cada caso.